# does AWS Lambda support HATEOS?

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, hateoas

- I am planning to implement REST APIs via AWS lambda and API Gateway
- Ideally i want to to implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS
  as well

Not sure if this is possible ? looking forward for inputs

Comment: https://github.com/hypermedia-app/Alcaeus

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Application_Language

Comment: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/odata-json-format-v4.01.html

Answer (score 1):

> Not sure if this is possible ? looking forward for inputs

It is.

Context first - the authoritative definition of REST, from which "hypermedia as the engine of application state", is [Chapter 5 of Fielding's dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2).

But the short version is: the interface should behave like web pages.

The easiest way to create an interface that behaves like web pages is to produce HTML documents.

So the question becomes: how do we arrange API Gateway and AWS lambda such that the resulting HTTP responses have HTML bodies?

[Set up Lambda proxy integrations in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) describes one way you might do that.  Basic idea being that API Gateway is going to transform the HTTP request into a JSON document with a particular schema, and then takes your response (a JSON document with a particular schema) and transforms that into a HTTP response.

Using HTML as your hypertext format is convenient; you can interact with the API using whatever general purpose web browser you happen to have at hand.

Does it have to be HTML?  No, it does not.  The mechanism is general purpose, so you can substitute whatever hypertext document format you prefer.

Comment: It probably can't be HTML, because HTML doesn't provide semantics/controls to create or update resources etc. for even the most primitive CRUD operations its very WWW relies on, so it's insufficient as a hypermedia format in ReST terms. Sure, WWW developers can use links (HTTP `GET`) for deleting a resource or a HTML form (HTTP `POST`) to update an existing resource, but these operations are not supported explicitly by the HTML semantics.

Short: If HATEOAS for WWW, use a better (if any) hypermedia format than HTML and AWS as mere remote server/storage, same with HATEOAS for non-WWW.